# Contouring Brush

Tags: weight-painting

[image]
I find the weight painting brush a bit flat, in fact it's pure 2 dimensional. Is there a way to get the brush to contour around the bend to paint in the same direction of the normals? If not, is there a 3d party alternative for better weight painting that is Blender friendly?

Comment: Can you clear the question,The brush isn't painting at higher angles?

Comment: Like the brush in Maya, it curves to the topology.

Comment: Unfortunately it is not implemented in blender,I don't know if it can be done in python.

Answer (score 1):

I think the "Inflate/Deflate" brush in Sculpt Mode will do the trick.

The default Inflate brush will move mesh vertices outward in the direction of their normals, and the reverse Deflate brush mode will move them inward.

Go into Sculpt mode and press <kbd>I</kbd> (for Inflate).  Then you can switch between Inflate and Deflate with the buttons in the Tools panel.

You can also use the trick of holding down <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> while sculpting to temporarily switch direction (I think that should also work for the other Sculpt brushes).

More here: https://www.blender.org/manual/painting_sculpting/sculpting/introduction.html

Comment: So you are telling me that I can weight paint with the sculpt brush? And it will show the weight colors in sculpt mode? What?

Comment: I guess I didn't really understand what "in the same direction as the normals" meant.  I thought it was a sculpting reference.

Comment: The brush circle is always parallel to the face of the polygon it is painting.

Answer (score 0):

Brushes in blender do not conform to the surface to follow it, though the only case where this mapping does work is when using procedural textures with a brush mapped to '3d' in sculpt, vertex and texture paint. The vertex weight paint doesn't use a texture so the 3d mapping is not available.

The brush itself is projected from the view, but the mappings override this as far as projection paint goes. You can get some 'follow' of your stroke from screen space using the Curve Stroke method by selecting 'Curve' in the drop down of stroke methods. The curve can be reused as long as you need it, but is based on view distance/pan/rotation so any movement to orbit might throw off your projection.[image: curve stroke with weight paint]